# Differentiate two instances of the same application in the dock

Tags: dock

I usually have to launch different instances of the same application (in my case of Eclipse).

I launch them from the terminal as follows

```
nohup /Applications/eclipse/eclipse -data ${workspace} 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

where `${workspace}` is different for each invocation.

Everything works well but for the fact that I cannot distinguish among instances in the Dock or while switching applications with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

[image]

Is there a way to differentiate them either by changing the application name under the icon or by dynamically changing the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution for your particular issue, and not OSX apps in general on which I believe do not have this issue.

[Workspace identifiers for Eclipse on OSX](http://njbartlett.name/2011/10/09/workspace-mac-badge.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great solution, but if you don't mind taking up a bit extra space, you could:

- find some other icon, and copy it to the clipboard
- make a copy of the Eclipse .app
- in the Finder, "Get Info"
- click the Eclipse icon, and paste your icon there
- from the Terminal, launch these two .apps, rather than the same app twice